# Copy and paste values from 2 differents db with a button

Tags: php, sql, controller

I have 2 databases on the same host with the same user on MariaDB through Navicat:

- DB1= auto
- DB2= auto2

They both have a table named `bg_users`

What I want to do is to update the attribute `"passwd"` and `"truepasswd"` in `auto2.bguser` from the corresponding fields in `auto.bguser` in accordance with the correct `"user"` reference.

I tried the below, but it failed:

```
update auth2.bg_user 
set user_id, truepasswd, passwd = auth.bg_user( truepasswd, passwd) 
where user_id = 891;
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to qualify all table fields and join both tables:

```
UPDATE auth2.bg_user, auth.bg_user 
  SET 
    auth2.bg_user.truepasswd = auth.bg_user.truepasswd,
    auth2.bg_user.passwd = auth.bg_user.passwd
  WHERE 
    auth2.bg_user.user_id = 891 AND 
    auth2.bg_user.user_id = auth.bg_user.user_id;
```

It is not tested, but should show you the way.

Comment: Thank you for your reactivy if there is a way i Can give you a thumbs up or a notation let me know i will try this then and give you the result or post it here

Comment: you can mark this as right answer, if it mets your requirements. there should be a link below of my text.

Comment: You are a genius all everyone go visit https://www.functions-online.com/ ! Omg it's working perfectly!